# Assign name to variable spatial object

Tags: r, loops, spatial, assign

I want to assign a set of names to a set of spatial objects, like this:

```
c_list <- c('A', 'B', 'C')

assign(c_list[1], SpatialObject)
```

But `assign()` does not work for spatial objects.

Any suggestions please ?

I tried:

```
do.call(<-, list(c_list[1], SpatialObject))
```

which also does not work (I thought I'd give it a try)

I imagine you can use do.call() to do this, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of spatial objects?

Comment: may you share some information of you SpatialObject such as `class` info which would be helpful. Though in R `assign('A', value)` should work perfectly fine for any kind of value. If you can provide the error message or something wrong with the assignment it would easier to figure out what going wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It does work. I've looked again and I was missing a bracket.

Comment: I got an error: "no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector" and assumed that it was the assign statement at fault.